# Console Goerli not functioning on Truffle - This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build

Tags: truffle, nodejs, truffle-migration, goerli

When i try to run npx truffle console --network goerli to start the console and then migrate my contracts on goerli testnet using truffle, I get the following error.

```
MacBook-Pro sample-nftrender % npx truffle console --network go
erli
This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build:

Error: Cannot find module './uws_darwin_x64_102.node'
Falling back to a NodeJS implementation; performance may be degraded.


Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)
    at hash160 (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:249:21)
    at HDKey.set (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:50:24)
    at Function.HDKey.fromMasterSeed (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:194:20)
    at Function.fromMasterSeed (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet/src/hdkey.ts:13:36)
    at HDWalletProvider.checkBIP39Mnemonic (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/src/index.ts:327:35)
    at new HDWalletProvider (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/src/index.ts:108:12)
    at Object.provider (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/truffle-config.js:91:24)
    at Object.getProvider (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/index.js:20:1)
    at Object.create (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/index.js:13:1)
    at TruffleConfig.get [as provider] (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/dist/configDefaults.js:275:1)
    at Object.detect (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/environment/environment.js:19:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/console/run.js:29:1)
    at runCommand (/Users/parikahlawat/Desktop/sample-nftrender/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command-utils.js:201:1)
Truffle v5.5.30 (core: 5.5.30)
Node v17.8.0
```

My truffle config file is:

```
/**
 * Use this file to configure your truffle project. It's seeded with some
 * common settings for different networks and features like migrations,
 * compilation, and testing. Uncomment the ones you need or modify
 * them to suit your project as necessary.
 *
 * More information about configuration can be found at:
 *
 * https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration
 * 
 * Hands-off deployment with Infura
 * --------------------------------
 *
 * Do you have a complex application that requires lots of transactions to deploy?
 * Use this appproach to make deployment a breeze ️:
 *
 * Infura deployment needs a wallet provider (like @truffle/hdwallet-provider)
 * to sign transactions before they're sent to a remote public node. 
 * Infura accounts are available for free at : https://infura.io/register
 *
 * You'll need a mnemonic - the twelve word phrase the wallet uses to generate
 * public/private key pairs. You can store your secrets  in a .env file. 
 * In your project root, run `$ npm install dotenv`. 
 * Create .env (which should be .gitignored) and declare your MNEMONIC 
 * and Infura PROJECT_ID variables inside.
 * For example, your .env file will have the following structure:
 * 
 * MNEMONIC = <Your 12 phrase mnemonic>
 * PROJECT_ID = <Your Infura project id>
 * 
 * Deployment with Truffle Dashboard (Recommended for best security practice)
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * 
 * Are you concerned about security and minimizing rekt status ?
 * Use this method for best security:
 * 
 * Truffle Dashboard lets you review transactions in detail, and leverages 
 * MetaMask for signing, so there's no need to copy-paste your mnemonic. 
 * More details can be found at : 
 * 
 * https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/using-the-truffle-dashboard/
 */

// require('dotenv').config();
// const { MNEMONIC, PROJECT_ID } = process.env;

// const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
require('dotenv').config()

const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

const mnemonic = process.env.MNEMONIC
const clientURL = process.env.ETH_CLIENT_URL
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Networks define how you connect to your ethereum client and let you set the
   * defaults web3 uses to send transactions. If you don't specify one truffle
   * will spin up a managed Ganache instance for you on port 9545 when you
   * run `develop` or `test`. You can ask a truffle command to use a specific
   * network from the command line, e.g
   *
   * $ truffle test --network <network-name>
   */

  networks: {
    // Useful for testing. The `development` name is special - truffle uses it by default
    // if it's defined here and no other network is specified at the command line.
    // You should run a client (like ganache, geth, or parity) in a separate terminal
    // tab if you use this network and you must also set the `host`, `port` and `network_id`
    // options below to some value.
    //
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
     },
    //
    // An additional network, but with some advanced options…
    // advanced: {
    //   port: 8777,             // Custom port
    //   network_id: 1342,       // Custom network
    //   gas: 8500000,           // Gas sent with each transaction (default: ~6700000)
    //   gasPrice: 20000000000,  // 20 gwei (in wei) (default: 100 gwei)
    //   from: <address>,        // Account to send transactions from (default: accounts[0])
    //   websocket: true         // Enable EventEmitter interface for web3 (default: false)
    // },
    //
    // Useful for deploying to a public network.
    // Note: It's important to wrap the provider as a function to ensure truffle uses a new provider every time.
     goerli: {
       provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, clientURL),
      network_id: 5,       // Goerli's id
      confirmations: 2,    // # of confirmations to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
       timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
      skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
     },
    //
    // Useful for private networks
    // private: {
    //   provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, `https://network.io`),
    //   network_id: 2111,   // This network is yours, in the cloud.
    //   production: true    // Treats this network as if it was a public net. (default: false)
    // }
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters, etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.17",      // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      //  optimizer: {
      //    enabled: false,
      //    runs: 200
      //  },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    }
  },

  // Truffle DB is currently disabled by default; to enable it, change enabled:
  // false to enabled: true. The default storage location can also be
  // overridden by specifying the adapter settings, as shown in the commented code below.
  //
  // NOTE: It is not possible to migrate your contracts to truffle DB and you should
  // make a backup of your artifacts to a safe location before enabling this feature.
  //
  // After you backed up your artifacts you can utilize db by running migrate as follows:
  // $ truffle migrate --reset --compile-all
  //
  // db: {
  //   enabled: false,
  //   host: "127.0.0.1",
  //   adapter: {
  //     name: "sqlite",
  //     settings: {
  //       directory: ".db"
  //     }
  //   }
  // }
};
```

I am trying to upload an ERC721 smart contract on Goerli. Kindly let me know where the issue is and if any other file is needed to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found the answer. Newer version (and for some reason odd versions) of Node have issues running with Truffle.

Install n or nvm
On Linux and macOS:

```
npm install -g n
```

n is not supported natively on Windows.

On Windows:
Use nvm.

Downgrading Node
After installing n, enter the following command to downgrade to any version of Node:

```
n <version>.
```

For example, running `n 10.24.0` will install Node version 10.24.0.

I setup with `n 14` which downgraded my node to v14.20.0 which worked perfectly.

Also another thing to note, `npx truffle develop` was necessary before entering console or migrate commands.

Answer (score 0):

the same error happened to me.
I found the source code below:

[image: 1]

Then I switched to node12 to match the Node Module 72, and it worked.
So you also need to switch to the right node version recording to the source code.

But I finally solve the ganache problem by node v18.12.1 to use uws_darwin_x64_108.node
[image]